# Assembly Load And Store 16 bits (half-word)

Tags: assembly, arm

If I am trying to convert this C code into assembly:

```
int16_t x, y;
x = y;
```

Then the corresponding assembly code would be:

```
LDRSH R0, y;
STRH R0, x;
```

Does it matter if I write `LDRSH R0, y;` Or `LDRH R0, y;` without the `S` in `LDRH`? Since in `int16_t x, y` x and y are both signed ints (16 bits) correct?

So would you use `LDRSH` or `LDRH` when loading y into the register R0?

Comment: because you are simply taking 16 bits in and writing 16 bits out, it doesnt matter what the other 16 bits in R0 end up being.

Comment: Oh I thought it would fill the remaining 16 bits in R0 with the most significant bit of `y`? So it would matter if you treat it as a signed or unsigned correct? Since if y is a negative number it would fill the most signficant 16 bits with 1?

Comment: Sure but as far as your one line of C code goes, you are taking 16 bits from one place and copying them to another.  the upper 16 bits of r0 dont matter it is the lower 16 bits that you are using to copy.  Now if you use x later, not show in the question then sure, you want to sign extend.

Comment: Ohh ok I see now! Thanks!

Comment: Also a quick question: If I had `uint64_t x;` and I say `x = 7;` in C. Would this be the correct Assembly code: `LDRD R0,R1 =7;` `STRD R0,x` ?

Comment: Oh ok, so my assembly code above with `LDRD/STRD` is correct?

Comment: actually no that is not how ldrd (nor stm) work.  first when you DO use ldrd, you only specify the even register the odd comes along with it.  you are doing an immediate, you cant do a 64 bit immediate in one instruction like that.    I will let you look in the docs to see which one is the most significant word I dont remember off hand, but for one you would   mov r0,#0 the other mov r1,#7.  strd r0,x

Comment: Ok Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `LDRH` and `LDRSH` is what is done about bits 31..16 of the destination: each bit of the destination will have the same value as bit 15 of the loaded data.

This is generally very useful because if the 16-bit number is negative, the 32-bit number will be negative as well.

In the very simple example you provide, it will not change anything because you only store it, but it would make a difference if you were doing operations (additions, multiplications, etc), as ARM processors will use 32-bit or 64-bit registers internally.

Comment: This may be a little off topic but I am trying to figure out the syntax... So if I had something like this: `int64_t x;` `x = 5` in C and want to convert to assembly. Would this be correct: `LDR R0, =5;` `LDR R1, =0` `STRD RO,R1,x` I am confused how which order to place the R0 and R1 in `STRD RO,R1,x`?

Comment: First register (`R0`) represents LSB (Address `x`), second one (`R1`) the MSB (Address `x+4`).